# UIAlertView crash by adding clickedButtonAtIndex

Tags: iphone, crash, uitextfield, uialertview

I create a class to call UIAlertview show on my screen. I write the UIAlert function in another class. **Both these two classes are not my viewController class**.

I use this UIAlert, which is a UITextfield inside, to store texts into a plist file.

here is the class to call UIAlert:

```
#import "Story.h"

@implementation Story

...
+ (void)stage1
{
    AlertClass *pointer = [AlertClass new];
    [pointer doAlert];
}
```

here is the class AlertClass.m file:

```
- (void)doAlert
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];

}
//this makes crash!
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    self.storyFlow.text = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
}
```

Before I add UIAlertViewDelegate in the .h and override the method "clickedButtonAtIndex", it works great. However, I need to store some data from the UITextfield inside the alert view. I get crash and don't know the message it responds as following.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

[crash pic] https://dl.dropbox.com/u/47381923/crash.tiff

Comment: Providing an image is not the best solution... At least if it was a jpeg or png... But it's a TIFF! Well, anyway... instead of raw assembly, it would be better if you copied over the stacktrace you got.

Comment: have you checked whether the text from alertview is valid and at the same time your self.storyFlow is initialized and not null?

Answer (score 0):

do an NSLog on the text you get back from the Alert View to see whether that is the crash or the subsequent 'self.storyFlow.text = ' is causing it. Perhaps self.storyFlow has not been created yet (with alloc/init)

Comment: I did an NSLog, it responded nothing. Even I leave empty inside "clickedButtonAtIndex" it still got crash..

Comment: if your AlertClass inherits from NSObject that it can't deal with the delegate alertView 'clickedAtButtonAtIndex' method; you need to put this in a view controller so that it ultimately inherits from UIView